# Facebook GraphAPI doesn't allow LetsEncrypt?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, lets-encrypt

Is there a reason why Facebook doesn't allow [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) signed certificates in their "app development" section?

I keep getting this error:
(For the untrained eye, this is me trying to setup a webhook for new messages notifications)
[image]

Blurred out the host, but it's a valid host and using chrome or firefox on Linux and Windows doesn't give any errors.

[SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) also says the site is perfectly valid.

[image]

Running `curl https://...` on my own host, sure enough I get the same error,

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
```

So my question is, why have Facebook (that openly supports LetsEncrypt) decided to use default curl CA bundle to verify the callback-url of an app? If that doesn't allow LetsEncrypt?

It appears to be counterproductive to me.
Is there a way around this?

Comment: _“SSLLabs also says the site is perfectly valid”_ – no, it doesn’t. If everything was _perfect_, then it would not show “Chain issues: Incomplete” in orange.

Comment: @CBroe That's because LetsEncrypt X3 certificate is an extra download, it's still valid, the X3 certificate is just not in the default key-store. At least to my understanding (They switched to a X3 cert about 10 months ago)

Comment: _Your server_ should present not only its own certificate, but the intermediate certificates as well.

Comment: @CBroe Ain't I a schmuck... Forgot the `ca-file` parameter in my SSL conf. Obviously I need to supply the intermediate certificate, I just thought it wasn't trusted in the store. Cheers! Sorry Facebook for bashing on you - My own fault! **Fun side-note**: Only Facebook Graph API (curl) and OSX(Apple) denies the certificate and deems it not valid for real. The rest accepts the certificate happily (some might throw a info notification about ti but allows it). Usually people bicker a lot about these companies, I'd like to give them credit for doing security pretty well in this regard :)

Comment: you should create an answer with that information, and accept it on your own :)

Comment: Thought I'd give @CBroe a change to earn the victory over my defeat :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> SSLLabs also says the site is perfectly valid.

It shows a warning in orange, that the certificate chain is incomplete.

Your server should present all necessary intermediate certificates as well, in addition to the certificate issued for your domain. (Which was simply forgotten here by mistake.)